# Best way to write a Camel Test on a Content Based Routing

Tags: apache-camel

I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed in writing a Simple Camel Test case for a CBR. Say I have this simple route:

```xml
<route id="_route1">
    <from id="_to1" uri="file:/home/user/data/eip-demo/in?noop=true"/>
    <choice id="_choice1">
        <when id="_when1">
            <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*xml$'</simple>
            <to id="_to2" uri="file:/home/user/data/eip-demo/xml"/>
        </when>
        <when id="_when2">
            <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*txt$'</simple>
            <to id="_to3" uri="file:/home/user/data/eip-demo/txt"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise id="_otherwise1">
            <log id="_log1" message="File unknown!"/>
             <to id="_to2" uri="file:/tmp"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

What is the most correct way to test this route? I think I could replace the file: component with a **direct**: component and Produce the files in the Test Case. However, then I will not be able to run the route directly from the IDE (Jboss Developer Studio). What is the most correct approach to coding a route like that which needs to be tested?

UPDATE: I've refined a bit the Camel Test created by JBoss Developer Studio:

```java
public class CamelContextXmlTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    // TODO Create test message bodies that work for the route(s) being tested
    // Expected message bodies
    protected Object[] expectedBodies = { "<something id='1'>expectedBody1</something>",
            "textfile" };
    protected Object[] name = { "test.xml",
    "test.txt" };

    // Templates to send to input endpoints

    @Produce(uri = "file:/home/data/eip-demo/in?noop=true")
    protected ProducerTemplate inputEndpoint;

    // Mock endpoints used to consume messages from the output endpoints and then perform assertions
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output")
    protected MockEndpoint outputEndpoint;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output2")
    protected MockEndpoint output2Endpoint;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output3")
    protected MockEndpoint output3Endpoint;

    @Test
    public void testCamelRoute() throws Exception {
        // Create routes from the output endpoints to our mock endpoints so we can assert expectations

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:/home/user/data/eip-demo/xml").to(outputEndpoint);

                from("file:/home/user/data/eip-demo/txt").to(output2Endpoint);
            }
        });

        // Define some expectations

        // TODO Ensure expectations make sense for the route(s) we're testing
        //outputEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(expectedBodies);

        // Send some messages to input endpoints
        int index=0;
        for (Object expectedBody : expectedBodies) {
            inputEndpoint.sendBodyAndHeader(expectedBody,"CamelFileName",name[index]);
            index++;
        }

        outputEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        output2Endpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        // Validate our expectations
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected ClassPathXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
    }

}
```

Is it a good solution or can it be improved?

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is AdviseWith:
http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

You simply need to replace/modify your endpoints on the fly OR simply add a mock on the fly after each condition of your CBR. If you couldn't do it, let me know and I will help with with some actual code that does this job for you.

R.